# Passing multimap data created in one class to another class

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Apologies if this is a trivial problem.

I'm trying to pass a multimap that has been put together with one class in a library to another class in that library in order to further manipulate the data there.

The code relates to a GUI written by other people and the classes here relate to two different tools in the GUI.

Very roughly speaking my code and what I'm after here is like this

```
class A
{
private:
    std::multimap<int, double> mMap;
    int anInt;
    double aDouble;
    ***some more definitions***
public:
    void aFunction(***openscenegraph node, a string, and a parser function***)
    {
        ***a few definitions are declared and initialised here 
        during calculations***
        ***some code calculating data stuff that 
        passes bits of that data to mMap (including information 
        initialised within the function)***
    }
}

class B
{
public:
    void bFunction(***openscenegraph node and some other data***)
    {
        ***I want to be able to access all the data in mMap here***
    }
}
```

Can anyone make it clear to me how I can do this, please?

Edit: Added to clarify what i'm aiming for

```
        //Edit by Monkone
        //section below is akin to what I'm trying to do
        class B
        {
        private:
            std::multimap<int, double> mMapb;
        public:
            std::multimap<int,double> bFunction2(A::MultiMapDataType data)
            {
                return mMap;
            }
            void bFunctionOriginal()
            {
                ***I want to be able to access all the data in mMap here***
                ***i.e. mMapb.bFunction2(mMap);***
                ***do stuff with mMapb***
            }
        }
```

However I can't get anything to actually do something like this

Comment: You might get that data from object `A` and pass it as an argument to `voidbFunction()` function.

Comment: What do you control? `class B` only?

Comment: Are `A` and `B` related? What are the constraints on the classes?

Comment: I can control both classes. As it stands the classes are in the same project in a multi-project solution. Data from other projects are passed to each of class A and B. What I'm stuck on is getting data to pass from class A to class B.

I simply do not adequately know how this might be done. I don't seem to be able to directly access anything made in class A in class B at the moment.

Comment: @Monkone You mean you want to change the `private` fields to `public` fields?

Comment: @kabanus
I tried that, however ```class B``` does not seem to see variables declared in other classes.

I've not had any luck with my attempts at using inheritance or friend either but that could easily just be me doing it wrong.

Comment: You could create `void A::bFunction(const B&);` or `void A::bFunction(<data_needed_for_calculation>);` if you'd like to keep direct access to `mMap` private.

Comment: That does not make sense. Please update the question itself with what you tried and what was the error you encountered - as it stands it's hard to tell what went wrong.

Comment: One more thing I thought of - are your classes fully defined in the header properly, rather than being defined in the `.cpp` file and only declared in the header?

Comment: @kabanus there are some things that get read into the map that seem to have been defined and initialised in the .cpp file. The map is defined in the header. Should I move the definition of every variable in each class to the header? Would that make a difference? I was under the impression that it shouldn't

Comment: The members themselves need to be defined in the header. Again, try and clarify your question - file structure, what is defined where, what is implemented where, what you tried (private->public) and how it failed.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the rough overview a little to better reflect what's going on. I'll try grabbing all of the members and move their definition to the header. I should point out that there is no compiling error here. The code works fine, I'm trying to add a new output into the gui and to do that I need data from class A in class B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I won't be needing to work on the map, only get information from it.

You could then add a function to return a const reference to the map and functions for returning const iterators to `A`:

```
class A {
public:
    typedef std::multimap<int, double> intdoublemap_t;
    typedef intdoublemap_t::const_iterator const_iterator;
    // typedef intdoublemap_t::iterator iterator;

private:
    intdoublemap_t mMap;

public:
    // direct access to the whole map
    const intdoublemap_t& getMap() const { return mMap; }

    // iterators
    const_iterator cbegin() const { return mMap.begin(); }
    const_iterator cend() const { return mMap.end(); }
    const_iterator begin() const { return cbegin(); }
    const_iterator end() const { return cend(); }

    /*
    iterator begin() { return mMap.begin(); }
    iterator end() { return mMap.end(); }
    */
};
```

Now you can iterate over the map from the outside (from `B`):

```
void bFunction(const A& a) {
    for(A::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it!=a.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << it->first << " " << it->second << "\n";
    }
}
```

Or access the map directly:

```
void bFunction(const A& a) {
    const A::intdoublemap_t& mref = a.getMap();
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however there's another snag :) I'm only able to work in c++ 98, and only able to work in VS 2008 without any form of intellisense or as-you-type function listings. It's really highlighted what I don't know...

Although I can google how to write that for loop in 98 style. It's really the issue of calling a function inside class B that passes the data directly there that's the issue

Comment: It really is. This isn't being helped by the fact that there is no int main() being worked with here and aFunction and bFunction both already have 4 other things being read into them within the GUI part of the program files.

I'm trying to convert something akin to what you've written into a second bFunction that gets called by the function in class B (which is attached to a button click in the GUI), but I'm still having no luck getting this map across.

Class B can't be called until class A has already been called as there's nothing there to toggle that's connected to class B until then.

Comment: if I want to only call in the multimap part of ```A``` in ```bFunction``` do I need to put it in as bFunction(A::mMap& a)?

```A``` as a class has a lot in it

Comment: No, the signatures of the two `bFunction`s I've made above should work as is.

Comment: Thanks, I'm afraid there's something still not right in what I'm doing but you and cprogrammer have both given my some good pointers. I'll keep tinkering about and hopefully something will work.

Comment: Great! Just add a new question if you're not getting it to work.

Comment: Hi I had a crack at your code but I seem to have misunderstood something. I posted a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55461590/passing-a-map-between-classes/55461696?noredirect=1#comment97640638_55461696

Comment: However I'm just too inexperienced or tired and just I can't see how any of the answers given apply. It's like having people on step 4 explaining to someone on step 1 that getting to step 4 is easy, you just go from step 3. Ok, but where's step 2?

Comment: I know the feeling. How do you make an instance of `A`  available to `bFunctionOriginal()`? Either `B` must inherit from `A` or you need to supply a reference or pointer to an instance of `A` to `B` via the constructor (that you save in `B`) or as an argument to `bFunctionOriginal()`. In my example, I supplied it as an argument to the function. If `B` _is an_ `A` you should perhaps go for inheritance, otherwise, composition.

Answer (score 0):

The C++ `private` members cannot be accessed by other (non friend) classed.
The first solution it would be to keep mMap private (not polite to work on other classes members) and offer assessors over it.

```
      class A
        {
        public:
            typedef std::multimap<int, double> MultiMapDataType;
        private:
            MultiMapDataType mMap;
            ***some more definitions***
        public:
            const MultiMapDataType& getConstMMap() const;
            MultiMapDataType getMMap();

    }

    class B
    {
    public:
        void bFunction(A::MultiMapDataType data)
        {
            ***I want to be able to access all the data in mMap here***
        }
        void bFunction2(const A::MultiMapDataType& data)
        {
            ***I want to be able to access all the data in mMap here***
        }
    }

    A a;
    B b;
    b.bFunction(a.getMMap());
    b.bFunction2(a.getConstMMap());
```

However, from architectural point, if you have multiple members that you need to share you should move them all in a new structure/class that encapsulates that functionality.

Comment: `getMMap()` should be `const` too I guess?

Comment: It was probably meant to return a reference, otherwise that method is pointless since you could assign the first version to a new variable for the same effect (assuming they just return `mMap`).

Comment: I'm not sure I follow here. Are you saying to create a function in class A that returns mMap and to call that function in class B on a multimap I create there in order to pass the data across?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't follow how this can solve the issue. I'm not fluent in c++ yet, could you explain this to me?

Comment: `getConstMMap` returs a const ref. `getMMap` returns a copy of the map. Working directly on the members of map si not ok, If you ***need*** to work on the members, then you actually need to move data (`mMap`) outside the class,

Comment: I won't be needing to work on the map, only get information from it. However I'm throwing myself through error valley here. I'm assuming I need to declare a multimap in ```class B``` and somehow apply getConstMMap() to it.

Comment: Then you need cost version  `b.bFunction2(a.getConstMMap());` does what you need

Comment: @cprogrammer Working directly on the _Values_ in the map is ok. Only the _Keys_ are off limits.

Comment: I've tried incorporating your method as a second function in class B that gets called in the first function but I'm getting the message "Illegal reference to non-static member 'A::mMap'

Comment: `A::mMap` is incorrect. use `A::MultiMapDataType` for data type, `a.getConstMMap()` to access actual data.

Comment: I can't seem to get anything like that, however, your approach is different to how I need to do this owing to the way I'm working within the framework of a large solution that is passing data to a GUI. This is a library I'm modifying.

I've put an edit into your post to indicate what I mean

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong place to put it. I've moved the clarification to my original post