# Passing a map between classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++98

This is in relation to an earlier question I had. I haven't managed to solve the problem there but for now I'm just trying to get better acquainted with the code to figure out how to deal with that problem.

Towards that goal, I've got around to trying out the suggestions given in that question and I'm a little stumped as to why the following isn't working.

in the header I have

```
class A {
public:
    typedef std::multimap<int, double> intdoublemap_t;
    const intdoublemap_t& getMap() const; 
    void setkey(int k);
    void setvalue(double v);
    void insertIntoMap();
    intdoublemap_t mMapA;

private:
    int key;
    double value;

};

class B {
public:
    typedef std::multimap<int, double> intdoublemap_t;
    void mapValues(const A& a);
private:
    intdoublemap_t mMapB;

};
```

in the implementation I have

```
const A::intdoublemap_t& A::getMap() const { return mMapA; }
void A::setkey(int k) { key = k; }
void A::setvalue(double v) { value = v; }
void A::insertIntoMap(){mMapA.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));}

void B::mapValues(const A & a){ const A::intdoublemap_t& mref = a.getMap();
                                mMapB = mref; }
```

and in main()

```
A a;
a.setkey(10);
a.setvalue(1232.2);
a.insertIntoMap();
B b;
b.mapValues(a);
```

The code compiles fine and everything to do with a works as expected but the map is not passing to b at all. It stays empty

Can anyone tell me why?

edit: I took another look at this and saw how to do it. I knew it was something stupidly basic. I just had to set mref in the function to a map in B and then could call a function to work on that map within B.

Comment: `const A::intdoublemap_t& mref = a.getMap();` creates a local reference to `a.getMap()` and shadows the data member `mref`.

Comment: I'm not sure what your intention is. If it's to make `this->mref` become a refernece to `a.getValue()` then this approach won't work. You'll need a pointer scheme, probably `std::share_ptr<intdoublemap_t>` to express shared ownership.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand

Comment: Ah, didn't see your second comment till I refreshed. The intention is to pass the map created in class A to class B.

I'm just trying to figure out how to do it so I can then implement the method into another project where I need to do something like this

Comment: The `mref` in ` const A::intdoublemap_t& mref = a.getMap();` is an entirely new variable with no relation to `this->mref`. You could write ` const A::intdoublemap_t& foo = a.getMap();` and have the exact same behavior. You likely meant to just write `mref = a.getMap();`.

Comment: *"to pass the map created in class A to class B"* isn't clear to me. Do you expect to copy the value? Move the value? Share a reference to the same value?

Comment: It's to do with modifying a GUI that I didn't write. I'm trying to to pass a map I created in one class to another class linked to another function in the GUI. I want to use that data to provide input to some further calculations that are then output in the GUI

Comment: I can't use shared_ptr because I have to use 98 for this. I feel like a lot of my troubles with this project would be solved simply by not having to use 98 but hey ho

Comment: Boost provides a solid alternative. Otherwise a pretty close approximation can be written in c++98, minus move semantics. I've added the c++98 tag to your question.

Comment: Thanks. I get what you're saying about mref but I'm not sure what would be the right syntax. Just ```mref = a.getMap();``` returns that mref is undefined

Comment: your class has a multimap member and a key/value pair of variable: this smells to me. Also, you have a getMap accessor for the public mmapA member, and weird naming: what the point in calling a member of A class somethingA (and somethingB for class B member)?

Comment: This isn't code being used for anything other than for me to practice passing a map from one class to another. I'm just labeling things to make it plain what they are.

There's zero danger of words being reused anywhere else cos this is all there ever will be here

Comment: If you are learing, there is zero danger for whatever you write. but since you are learning, it's the right time to use good habits such a good naming convention

Comment: Fair enough, I still haven't solved this issue though. I don't understand the answers

Answer (score 2):

As @FrancoisAndrieux notes, your `getMap()` only sets a reference local to the function - not the class' `intdoublemap_t mref`. If you want the latter to be a reference to a map elsewhere, you have three options:

- Make it `intdoublemap_t& mref`, initialize it *on construction* of the B instance.
- Make it `std::reference_wrapper<intdoublemap_t> mref`, set it whenever you want (e.g. in `mapValues()`.
- Make it `intdoublemap_t*` (or `std::shared_ptr<intdoublemap_t>` in both A and B), set it whenever you like.

<sub>Note: As @FrancoisAndrieux says in a comment, with the second and third option (and without `std::shared_ptr`) you will have to be careful not to allow the reference to be used after the original object's lifetime has expired.</sub>

Having said all the above - I must also say that your design seems rather off to me. You should really not be doing any of these things and I'm 99% sure you're approaching your task the wrong way.

Comment: For the 2nd solution and the 3rd solution if you don't use `shared_ptr` you will find that lifetime management for the actual `intdoublemap_t` will be difficult to and will probably resolve to using `std::shared_ptr` anyway.

Comment: What other options are there for passing data between classes? I have next to no idea how to do this and trying to google approaches left me baffled as to how to implement anything into the larger project and so I strove to go for what seemed to be the simplest approach: just pass a map of data from one class to the other. Not turning out to be so simple

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying your suggestions and only getting errors. How are your suggestions supposed to fit in what I've written?

Please, don't treat me like I know what I'm doing here. Explain it like I'm 5

Comment: @Monkone: I don't see how your classes make sense.

Comment: That's probably because a) it's an attempt to learn a work around for another problem and b) I'm new to c++. I mean, I kind of understand einpoklums suggestions but before heading to bed last night I didn't see how to fit any of his suggestions into my code. I suspect mref needs changing to cref to use his reference_wrapper suggestion